# Access project.version from pom.xml in an angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, maven

I have an angular web app. I need to access the version in the pom.xml to display in app.component.html.
I have the following in my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

How can I access this ${project.version} in my app.component.html or app.component.ts?

Comment: You already use filtering.  What does not work for you?

Comment: When I try to access it in app.component.html as follows, it just shows ${project.version} instead of the actual version. <span [innerHTML]="'${project.version}'"></span>